# How to set BitmapFactory.Option to bitmap object?

Tags: android, bitmap, ram

I have a function that uses file path to access a JPG file on sdCard and create a bitmap of it. It uses inSampleSize to make a RAM compatible bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String imgPath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,reqWidth,reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
    }
```

Now I wanna pass a bitmap to this function instead of imgPath like this:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
```

I want to do that because I have multiple bitmaps on screen. I can use a large temp bitmap but I cant add that to my bitmap list because of memory issues. BitmapFactory does not have this option. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Now I wanna pass a bitmap to this function instead of imgPath" -- why? You already have the `Bitmap` in memory. If you want to create a scaled edition of it, use [`createScaledBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)).

Comment: @CommonsWare InSampleSize is a screen dependent number. I can not calculate it with createScaledBitmap().

Comment: So? If you use `createScaledBitmap()`, you do not need `inSampleSize`. You merely need the size of the desired bitmap. You already know this, as you are passing those values into `calculateInSampleSize()`.